# MVC create view Jquery show and hide

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a MVC project and in the create view I only want certain div's to show when a user presses a button.

I made something that is working.

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_div_fun(id) {

        var divelement = document.getElementById(id);

        if (divelement.style.display == 'none')
            divelement.style.display = 'block';
        else
            divelement.style.display = 'none';
    }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggle_div_fun2(id) {

        var divelement = document.getElementById(id);

        if (divelement.style.display == 'none')

            divelement.style.display = 'block';

        else
            divelement.style.display = 'none';
    }

</script>
```

Html:

```
<button onclick="toggle_div_fun('Content');">Content</button>
<button onclick="toggle_div_fun2('Image');">Image</button>


        <div class="form-group", id="Content">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemContent, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextArea("ItemContent", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "De inhoud van het item content", rows = "6", cols = "20" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemContent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group", id="Image">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ItemContent, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", type = "date", @placeholder = "Kies hier de foto" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ItemContent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

This seems to work.
Everytime I press a button the div will go away.But 
i want to make it so that the div isn't shown yet until I press a button and then it will show the div.

Would any of you guys please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the initial display state using CSS rules

```
#Content, #Image { display:none; }
```

Additionally,  the function `toggle_div_fun2` is redundant as performs the same operation as `toggle_div_fun` based on input parameter. So remove one of them.

Comment: actually since its mvc and he may be using bootstrap just calling the hidden class to the elements should do why create additional css?

Comment: @RAHULSR, You correctly pointed out, _may be_ and using `hidden` will do the job no need to create additional css

Answer (score -1):

You are using Jquery so you could you show/hide controls.

```
    $("#Content").show();

    $("#Content").hide();
```